# Lambda multiple conditions to select objects from List<T>

Tags: c#, list, select, lambda, conditional-statements

I 'm using c# to select some objects in a List. The following code is working.

```
public void filterByWork(string work, int precision)
        {
            workResults = new List<FbUser>();
            Array keywords = work.Split(' ');
            workResults = userlist.Where(user => user.work != null);
            workResults = workResults.Where((user => user.work.Any(wrk => StringExtensions.match(wrk.employer.name, keywords) >= precision)));

        }
```

But what if i want more than one condition? Can i use the 'OR' keyword somewhere? Because i want to select all objects where the wrk.employer.name = "something" OR wrk.position.name = "something". How can do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply use the normal `||` operator:

```
workResults = workResults.Where((user => 
                  user.work.Any(wrk => wrk.employer.name == "something" || 
                                       wrk.position.name == "something")
                               ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could just use C#s or operator (`||`).

Comment: too true. however, since this is SO (where actually helping regardless of question is high in regard) my vote is with the answer that shows an example on this one